Beamer transparent overlay for subitems
I'm trying to create a presentation where all the bullet points in a frame are greyed out except the one I'm currently talking about, so I used the transparent option, like so:
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{pifont} %Itemize bullet style [mandatory to use specific symbols from this package]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item[\ding{110}] one
\item[\ding{110}] two
\item[\ding{110}] three
\item[\ding{110}] four
\item[\ding{110}] five
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

It worked as intended. But, when I used sub-items I'm not getting the desired results. What I'm getting is the bullet points are greyed out in the beginning but as I progress the points that I talked about previously are not greyed out, it doesn't appear uniform. What I did:
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item[\ding{110}] one
\item[\ding{110}] two
\item[\ding{110}] three
\begin{itemize}[<.->]
\item[\ding{111}] three point one
\item[\ding{111}] three point two
\item[\ding{111}] three point three
\end{itemize}
\item[\ding{110}] four
\item[\ding{110}] five
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

I want every point to be greyed out except the one I'm currently talking about, and as the talk progresses I want the older points to remain greyed, like the first example above. How do I get this?

In your second example, you use \begin{itemize}[<+->]. The <+-> means that your bullet points will be uncovered from the next overlay (+) onwards until the end of the frame (-).
If you only want to have them uncovered on one overlay, remove the +.
To avoid double transparency for the sublist, you can replace <.-> with <1-> (or remove it). The sublist will automatically be covered together with its parent item.
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item[\ding{110}] one
\item[\ding{110}] two
\item[\ding{110}] three
\begin{itemize}[<1->]
\item[\ding{111}] three point one
\item[\ding{111}] three point two
\item[\ding{111}] three point three
\end{itemize}
\item[\ding{110}] four
\item[\ding{110}] five
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


